# BC30928 Project Failed to Build

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

My system got corrupted two days ago and i have lost all my projects too. I had git backup of my project which is few months old, after downloading from git and it showed me the following issue.
[image]

i am unbale to install .Net 4.0 as it says "a newer or Higher version of the framework already installed", so i tried downloading the closest version available ehich is .Net 4.5.1

But the project failed to build with following error, i tred .Net 4.5.1 & 4.8

`"BC30928 Base class 'ObjectContext' specified for class 'My_ProjectEntities' cannot be different from the base class 'DbContext' of one of its other partial types."`

*I am using Visual Studio 2022 with Windows 11 Pro*

Comment: Is it possible NuGet pulled EF6 while you had previously used EF5?

Comment: What harm would it be to simply update your project to use 4.8?

Comment: @Hursey the project simply unable to build and throws "BC30928 Base class 'ObjectContext' specified for class 'My_ProjectEntities' cannot be different from the base class 'DbContext' of one of its other partial types."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing Model1.edmx fixed my issue of

`"BC30928 Base class 'ObjectContext' specified for class 'My_ProjectEntities' cannot be different from the base class 'DbContext' of one of its other partial types."`

Then instead of trying to install dot net 4.0, updated to reccomended version of dot net 4.8.

later I had to update all my NuGet packages and then reinstall sqlTypes to fix some issue. hope this might help someone